# Как узнать текущий день недели

Tags: jquery

JQ есть возможность узнать по дате какой там был день недели..

А можно ли узнать день недели текущий и как?

Comment: `(new Date()).getDay()` - без jq

Comment: Или так: ```'ВсПнВтСрЧтПтСб'.match(/../g)[(new Date).getDay()]```

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, напишите свой коммент как ответ, я его выберу как правильный) Спасибо))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getWeekDay(date) {
    date = date || new Date();
    var days = ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'];
    var day = date.getDay();

    return days[day];
}
```

Использовать:

```
var date = new Date();

alert(getWeekDay(date));
```

И никакого JQ ненужно

Comment: Неужто я настолько не правильно сформулировал :D                           Мне нужно как у, например,  `.getHours() //21:24`, чтобы можно было проверку на день недели сделать)                                                              Или всё таки придётся велосипед собирать на основе Вашего ответа?)

Comment: Первый ответ из комментариев самый подходящий ^^ Я прост не стал дублировать его и предположил что возможно как-то форматировать нужно будет ;-)